# Jenkins jobs, history, users - all missing after a reconfigure

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

This question has been asked multiple times around however 'Reload from disk' didn't work for me.

I opened my local Jenkins after a month, this time it asked me to reconfigure everything including the plugins as well as admin user (it had generated a new password). Moreover, my old jobs, build history, scripts etc. everything has gone missing. I have tried 'Reload from disk', but it did not work. I checked for most known places to see if my folders are available but they aren't.

Please can anyone help me get at least my scripts back?

Comment: Unless you manually deleted the directory, you just need find where the JENKINS_HOME directory is and point back to there. It's usually in "C:\Users\Owner\.jenkins" if run manually, or if via the installer "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins". How were you running it? Are you running as a different user?

Comment: Thanks! I have not deleted the directory, nor have I changed the location, because the last time I was trying to change it to a folder of my choice but the setting won't reflect even on multiple restarts. The same user, in fact I hadn't even created a user last time around and just used Jenkins as admin, since only I use this laptop. As I mentioned it made me walk through the entire set up including reinstall of the plugins.

Comment: It is not recognizing any old users. I use ngrok, if that information helps.